# IDE for pyglet?

Tags: python, windows, ide, pyglet

I'm starting to code with **pyglet** in **Windows**. I usually rely on Spyder as an **IDE**, but it seems not to like pyglet. So what would be a convenient way to code / run pyglet in Windows? What is your minimal development setup? Short of obvious minimal setups such as running code on Console2 or using IDLE.

Comment: Spyder dev here :) In which way pyglet is not working for you? I worked with Vpython a lot with no problems but I don't know how different it is from pyglet.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I just ran a simple Hello World with Pyglet and Spyder and it seems to run fine... At this moment I don't remember what I was doing when I bumped into a problem. Will let you know if I encounter one again.

Comment: are there any code completion problems, or lack of template generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at [Pydev](http://pydev.org/) for eclipse?

Comment: Yep. I have it running. Although I defected to Spyder for my data analysis. I am coming to the conclusion that IDEs like better the language in which they were built. :7D

Comment: Pydev (which uses eclipse) is quite good. For smaller projects, or ones that only have a couple of files, I will use Scintilla/notepad++/etc...

Answer (score 3):

If you're working specifically with windows only, there's another great option: Visual Studio using the [Python Tool for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/).

You do not need the full fledged Visual Studio package, it works with a stripped-to-bones version by Microsoft called Integrated Shell that is free to use (as in no-costs; see instructions on the python tools website). The plugin itself is free (as in Apache license).

I used the spyder IDE myself before switching. Feature-wise I believe there are quite comparable: Syntax Highlighting, code completion, integrated console and full debugger user. The difference is that the python tools integrate perfectly into the standard VS debugging workflow, using breakpoints, watching and evaluating variables and function at any point during debugging etc. If you've ever worked in Visual Studio you'll just love it. Best Python debugger I've come across.

I used it in the past to debug a Panda3D application (a 3D game engine for python). Since pyglet is also using openGL, it should work, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 2):

I use [pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/). It is free and has many useful features like predicting text and works fine with pyglet.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (there is also a free community edition). Among other helpful features (debugger, version control etc) it provides viewing images inside the IDE which is especially useful when it comes to game programming.

Answer (score 0):

pycharm, I would highly recommend. The free version has all you need, and is very highly organised. I use it all the time. You'll need to copy your pyglet file into every project tho. Still, it's easy to use and functional, and comes with a lot of good tools.